# The (nearly) best way to manage a list with shifting items

Tags: c#, performance, list

Here is the situation:
I have list which store strings which are actually numbers and can become pretty big (hundreds of millions of items).
I store the numbers as string because there is a option to display some additional information which is text.

Because this takes a lot of memory to store I decided that I will store only a maximum of 5 million items. (this will only take about 250-300mb).

The list is filled by the output of a calculation. If a number is found it will be added to the list, this number is always bigger than the existing items.

When the list reached 5 mil I want to remove the first item and add the new item to the list.

like:

```
    // Why is this so freaking slow???
    if (_result.Count == 5000000)
        _result.RemoveAt(0);
    _result.Add(result);
```

As you can read in the comment, this is very, very, very slow. It just cut down my performance by 15 times. Where it took 2 minutes it now takes about 30.

I tried a few things with linq like `.Skip(1).ToList` but that will recreate the list and is therefore even more slow.

The list must stay in the right order, so overwriting by index is not an option (unless you could explain a nice work around).

My question:
**Is there any decent way to do this?**

I really need the performance here since it may need to check up about 10000000000 numbers. This may take a day ofcourse, but a month is a bit too much :(.

Need additional information, feel free to ask, I'll be happy to supply.

**Solution:**
This performs O(1)

```
    // Set the _result
    Queue<object> _result = new Queue<object>(5000000);

    /// Inside the method
    // If the count has reach it's max, dequeue the first item
    if (_result.Count == 5000000)
        _result.Dequeue();
    _result.Enqueue(result);
```

Comment: Is there a compelling reason that you have to use a list? Can you use a SQLite database instead

Comment: @user1556110 The application must be able to run on any computer and in memory, I don't know if that is possible in SQLite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you ever reorder items? If you don't, a circular queue would work quite well.

System.Collections.Generic.Queue is one, I just double checked.

To expand on the benefits of a Queue, this is the `RemoveAt` implementation (roughly):

```
for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
    items[i-1] = items[i];
count--;
```

Because `list[0]` is always the first item, you have to move everything to remove the first item.

In contrast, a queue tracks the first item separately. This changes the above code to this:

```
head++
```

Comment: Thanks for the namespace, I will check it out :).

Comment: I actually do reorder the items in some way. I will reverse the list at the end, but it is easy to omit that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did the trick, I will post my solution in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to better implement a circular queue. Then you push every int to the end of the queue and when you run out of space (determined by the fixed size) then each operation will require to pop the first and push on the bottom. `O(1)`.

Advantage vs. Array is that you'll not preallocate space until it's needed. But, last, consider REALLY to store ints as, well, ints. No matter what operations you'll perform you should always store numbers as numbers.

Comment: Do you suggest then that I should keep two arrays, one for the numbers and the other for in case the user wants additional information?

Comment: No. I'm not even suggesting arrays use. What I encourage you to think is if you really need to have the additional information with your integers. If that's the case, good, if not, if you can say calculate the info based on the number, then just store the number.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will see what's possible.

Comment: I would disagree that you should always store numbers as numbers, if you aren't doing math and don't need the memory, storing numbers as strings can avoid sizing issues.

Comment: @Guvante Sure for that cases, but as the OP says "The application must be able to run on any computer and in memory" I will not make any memory guarantee if must run on ANY, better to be humble in consumption. Plus, better be prepared for extensibility.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you preallocate the array, and have two integers, indicating the start and the end of the array. Obviously, they would both start off equal to 0. Once you run out of room, you just start to wrap around.

An example psuedo helper class:

```
class CircularArray
{
  const int maxSize = 5000000;
  private int[] arr = new int[maxSize];
  private int start = 0;
  private int end = 0;

  public void Add(int value)
  {
    int newEnd = (end + 1) % maxSize;
    if (newEnd == start)
      start = (start + 1) % maxSize;
    end = newEnd;
    arr[end] = value;
  }

  public int Get(int index)
  {
    int newIndex = (start + index) % maxSize;
    return arr[newIndex];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you remove the first item in an ArrayList, all other items are shifted down. A circular que would allow you to keep the original order and eliminate the time consuming shifts that occur when you remove the head of the list.

Answer (score 0):

May be [`LinkedList<T> Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx) may help you? Removing and adding at the both ends is O(1) operation, but iteration will be O(n), or if you need O(1) on accessing you can use `Dictionary` or [`SortedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx)
Another custom-implementation is `QueueDictionary`, i used it when i need O(1) operation on both add and remove at the end or start (Queue/Dequeue) and on accessing a value. QueueDictionary here: [How would I implement a QueueDictionary, a combination of Queue and Dictionary in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3965516/1460957)